# wkhtmltopdf loading pages error in powershell script

Tags: powershell, wkhtmltopdf

i am running the wkhtmltopdf from a powershell script on a windows machine.
the command i am using is

```
& "C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe"    "C:\Desktop\Test.htm"  "C:\Desktop\Report.pdf"
```

the pdf file is getting created but it is also throwing an error as

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe : Loading pages (1/6)
At line:1 char:2
+ & <<<<  "C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe"     "C:\Test.htm"  "D:\Report.pdf"
+ CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Loading pages (1/6):String) [], RemoteException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : NativeCommandError

[>                                                           ] 0%[======>                                                         ] 10%[==============================>                             ]
50%[============================================================]  100%Counting pages (2/6)                                               
[============================================================] Object 1 of  1Resolving links (4/6)                                                       
[============================================================] Object 1 of  1Loading headers and footers (5/6)                                           
Printing pages (6/6)
[>                                                           ]   Preparing[============================================================] Page 1  of 1Done
```

due to which i am unable to proceed further as the script is returning    error.
please suggest help on this.

Comment: It would appear that `wkhtmltopdf.exe` is sending output to the error stream. Are you able to do something like this `$result = & "C:\Program Files\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe" "C:\Desktop\Test.htm"  "C:\Desktop\Report.pdf"`. It is not an error per sei. Just is coming via the error stream so PowerShell is treating it as one. If you can capture the output then you wont see those messages.

Comment: hi @matt,  thanks a lot for the prompt reply.but after doing the suggested changes also i am facing the same error.please  get me through,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to handle the error text that is generated. Lets put std err to std out and capture the results ( in case you want to review them )

```
$result = & 'C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe' 'www.google.ca' "c:\temp\pdf.pdf" 2>&1
```

If the actual console output is not important you could just send it to `Out-Null`

```
& 'C:\Program Files (x86)\wkhtmltopdf\bin\wkhtmltopdf.exe' 'www.google.ca' "c:\temp\pdf.pdf" 2>&1 | Out-Null
```

Answer (score 1):

The above accepted answer that says to capture the results didn't work for me, but looking at the WKHTMLTOPDF documentation i found the correct way to suppress the info text (which is output by default).

You need to set --log-level to error so that it will only output genuine error text and not the info text which powershell is mis-interpreting as an error.

```
  --log-level <level>             Set log level to: none, error, warn or
                                  info (default info)
```